# Table View Data Source in MVVM-C

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift, rxdatasources

where should I put UITableView Data Sources (I am using RxDataSources) when using MVVM-C architecture?

Comment: it depends on what you want. It can be an extension of UIViewController, or your custom class which will be allocated in UIViewController, all other vcs must be inherited from super class where your dataSource implemented

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik What has view controller inheritance got to do with the question? Besides your claim regarding inheritance must be all wrong

Comment: @JoakimDanielson VCSuperClass(contains dataSource) -> InheritedVC(access methods to override properties dataSource basedOn). If using Rx there will be PublishedSubject in superClass which will be changed by viewModel in InheritedVC

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik Well if this is a requirement for MVVM I will certainly stay away from it. And I don't understand why a data source for a table view must be accessible from a multitude of view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MVVM pattern design. You can put your `AnimatableSectionModel` stuff in your ViewModel. And in your viewController observe and bindTo your tableView datasources.